# How to split combined string into multiple strings in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, foreach

How can I split this array with commas?
I have multiple arrays 

[ "LeadershipPress" ]

[ "BusinessLeaderLeadershipPress" ]

[ "LeaderLeadershipPoliticsPress" ]
etc.

```
scraper.scrapeListingPages('article.article', (item) => { 
    var categories = $(item).find('a[rel = "category tag"]').text().split();
    console.log(categories);
    categories.forEach(function(i){
       $(i).find('a[rel = "category tag"]')
       console.log(i);
    })
});
```

Right now my output in the console is

```
Array [ "BusinessLeaderLeadershipPress" ]
BusinessLeaderLeadershipPress
```

I want to split the categories into an array with commas without having to use separator, limits or regex because I have multiple random arrays.

Is there a way I can use a forEach or for loop to accomplish this?

The result I want is [ "Business, Leader, Leadership, Press" ]

Thanks

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: There are no commas in the strings, how can you split it with commas?

Comment: You need to put the separator as the argument to `split()`. Otherwise it makes an array of single characters.

Comment: What is the text you're receiving? That first bit with individual categories in one-length arrays? If you're receiving that as output, apply [`Array.prototype.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to the `categories` array. Also see [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) for more information on proper splitting.

Comment: do you have some examples of the strings and the wanted results?

Comment: Ive added my expected output as an edit, [ "Business, Leader, Leadership, Press" ]. I want it to come out like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> without having to use separator, limits or regex because I have
> multiple random arrays.

A simple approach using `for-loop` with ***algorithm*** taking Consideration that string starts with *Uppercase*:
Looping through characters of the string
if char is not ***UPPERCASE*** accumelate chars to variable **`word`**, until encounter *Uppercase* letter, then push it in `res` Array.

```js
const string = "BusinessLeaderLeadershipPress";
let i = 1;
let character = "";
let word = string[0];
const res = [];
while (i <= string.length) {
  character = string.charAt(i);
  if (character == character.toUpperCase()) {
    res.push(word);
    word = character;
  } else {
    word += character;
  }
  i++;
}
console.log(res); //['Business', 'Leader', 'Leadership', 'Press']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could split a string with a look ahead for an uppercase letter.

```js
const
    string = 'BusinessLeaderLeadershipPress',
    result = string.split(/(?=[A-Z])/);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked! I dont know how to use regex and wasnt sure how to go about it but this was very helpful thank you!